# "ArgumentException: The incoming token has expired. Get a new access token from the Authorization Server

Tags: php, microsoft-translator

when i write this url :
"http://api.microsofttranslator.com/V2/Ajax.svc/Translate?from=EN&to=AR&text=hello&appId=Bearer%20http%253a%252f%252fschemas.xmlsoap.org%252fws%252f2005%252f05%252fidentity%252fclaims%252fnameidentifier%3DCollinsDictionary%26http%253a%252f%252fschemas.microsoft.com%252faccesscontrolservice%252f2010%252f07%252fclaims%252fidentityprovider%3Dhttps%253a%252f%252fdatamarket.accesscontrol.windows.net%252f%26Audience%3Dhttp%253a%252f%252fapi.microsofttranslator.com%26ExpiresOn%3D1438932547%26Issuer%3Dhttps%253a%252f%252fdatamarket.accesscontrol.windows.net%252f%26HMACSHA256%3DIXw8MGah7RNaFvvFVCpUDEprMEKTuNWptn%252bOQ6jMjrE%253d&oncomplete=__transferoCallback_2" than it returns me this exception, i think the reason of this ecception is that after every 10 minutes the page get expired, is there any way to get rid of this exception ?

Comment: Why don't you ask their support? They should be able to provide the best answer.

Comment: i tried there also but didnt find the suitable answer

Comment: I did not mean to look at the FAQ section, but to contact them. They should be able to answer to a question, shouldn't they? On the other hand, that is Microsoft. I never received any reply from them for a support request... (which is why I don't use them any more...)

Comment: @arkascha - Saying something like "*that is Microsoft*" - I don't see how your commentary about your opinions of a company help in any way. This is a programming Q&A site.